# jQuery colorbox - getting called even after closing

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am facing a weird problem. I do need to show a popup when checking a checkbox. It works fine, but the same popup appears even during unchecking.

```
<af:objectImage id="agreementCheckBoxImg" source="/base/images/spacer.gif" styleClass="jqTransformCheckbox" onclick="displayPopup(this.id,'main\\\\:content\\\\:Popupregion\\\\:Popup','520px','260px');return false;"/>

<script type="text/javascript">    
    function displayPopup(buttonId,popId,width,height) {
        var eminputSelf = $("#main\\:content\\:check");
        if (eminputSelf.attr("checked") == true) { // check box condition works fine
            alert('returning do not show popup');
        } else {
            $('#'+needHelpId).colorbox({ open:true, title:'',innerWidth:interWidth, innerHeight:innerHeight,close:'shutdown', inline:true, href:popId , onOpen:function(){ $(popId ).show();}, onCleanup:function(){ $(popId ).hide();}});
        }
    }

</script>
```

The alert is coming during uncheck, but the popup also coming.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?  The checkbox event listener?  What's calling the `if/else` above?  The HTML might also be helpful if somebody wants to put together a demo for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
if (eminputSelf.prop("checked") === true) {
```

`prop()` returns boolean values and changes with the checkbox state, while `attr()` does not.

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: this condition is working fine, and returns without calling the else. But still the popup comes.

Comment: I'm calling baloney on that.  Clearly your else condition is being called, or you are calling the modal from somewhere else in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
if (eminputSelf.is(":checked")) { // checked condition
  // existing code
} else {
  // existing code  
}
```

Good Luck !!

Comment: this condition is working fine, and returns without calling the else part. But still the popup comes.

Comment: I have shared the code, but couldn't share as it is using custom components.

Comment: @Vanathi, "needHelpId" this argument is not passed in the function. How are you getting this?